# Issues Switching From UIKit to SwiftUI and Passing API Data to the View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, swiftui

I just converted my app to the SwiftUI framework. The front end works great, but I am having a huge issue - I can't figure out how to fetch my data from a user UITextField entry and update my view. This project has a lot of code, but I've condensed it into a few files and will share only a portion since the other portions of the app are structured in a similar manner. I would really appreciate help anyone can offer. I intend to replace many of the strings in the `METARView` Text labels with variables based on the decoded API call data.

Front End: ContentView()

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Aviate
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/27/20.
//
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class Query: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    
    @State var stationQuery: String = ""

    
    
    var body: some View {

            NavigationView{
           
                VStack {
                    Text("The App for GA Pilots")
                    Spacer()
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("News")
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                            
                        Text("Aviate now supports chart lookup functionality!")
                            .padding()
                            
                            
                        
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    
                    
                    
                        
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        
                        Text("Favorite Airports")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                        
                        
                        List {
                            
                            
                            Section(header: Text("Favorite Airports")) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: METARView(search: stationQuery)) {
                                Text("Airport 1")
                            }
                            }
                            
                            Section(header: Text("Nearby Stations")) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: METARView(search: stationQuery)) {
                                Text("Airport 1")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    
                        }
                    

                    Spacer()
                    
                    
                    HStack{
                        TextField("Enter ICAO", text: $stationQuery)
                            .padding()
                            .border(Color.black)
                            
                        NavigationLink(destination: METARView(search: stationQuery)) {
                            Text("Search")
                            

                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    
                    
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Aviate Home")
                
           
    }
        
    }
    
    
    
}





struct METARView: View {

    
    @State var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
       
       init(search: String) {
           self.weatherManager.fetchWeather(stationICAO: search)
       }

    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        ScrollView{
            
            METARReport(model: weatherManager.weather)
            MapView()
                .frame(height: 200)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            METARTitleView()
                .frame(height: 250)
               
            METARReport()
                
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
    
    
}

struct TAFView: View {

    var search: String

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView{
            MapView()
                .frame(height: 200)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            METARTitleView()
                .frame(height: 250)
               
            TAFReport()
                
           
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}


struct AirportView: View {

    var search: String

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView{
            MapView()
                .frame(height: 200)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
               
            AirportReport()
                
           
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone 11")
        
    }
}



final class DataModel: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = DataModel()
  @Published var observedString = "" {
    didSet {
      //RUNS SUCCESSFULLY
      print("Observed string changed to \(observedString)")
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the part of METARView() that is needed to understand where the data is going - it will present the pulled data.

METARReport()

```
//
//  METARReport.swift
//  Aviate
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/29/20.
//

import SwiftUI
import Foundation


var weatherManager = WeatherManager()



struct METARReport: View {
    

    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("METAR Report")
                    .font(.title)
                    
                Spacer()
                Text("Time: " + "")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            
            .padding()
            
            HStack{
                Text("Flight Rules")
                  
                Spacer()
                Text("VFR")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
                 
            }
            .padding()
            .font(.headline)
            
                HStack(spacing: 20){
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Visibility")
                          
                        Spacer()
                        Text("10" + " SM")
                            
                           
                    }
                    
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Temperature")
                          
                        Spacer()
                        Text("25" + " °C")
                         
                           
                    }
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Dew Point")
                          
                        Spacer()
                        Text("25" + " °C")
                           
                           
                    }
                 
            }
            .padding()
            .font(.headline)
                
                VStack(alignment: .center){
                    Text("Clouds")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        
                    HStack() {
                        Text("Few")
                        Spacer()
                    
                        Text("1200")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    HStack() {
                        Text("Few")
                        Spacer()
                    
                        Text("1200")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    HStack() {
                        Text("Few")
                        Spacer()
                    
                        Text("1200")
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .font(.headline)
            
                HStack{
                    Text("Altimeter")
                      
                    Spacer()
                    Text("29.92")
                     
                }
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
                
                VStack{
                    Text("Wind")
                    HStack{
                        Text("5" + "kt")
                        Text("G")
                        Text("12" + "kt")
                        Text("From")
                        Text("310" + "°")
                        
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                }
                .font(.headline)
            
                HStack {
                    Text("Special Wx")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("+RA")
                }
                .padding()
                .font(.headline)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Remarks")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("No Remarks")
                }
                .padding()
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }
    }
}

struct METARReport_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        METARReport()
    }
}
```

Back End: WeatherStorage (Contains WeatherData, WeatherModel, and WeatherManager with API Call)

```
struct WeatherData: Codable {
   
    let flight_rules: String?
    let remarks: String?
    let wind_speed: WindSpeed?
    let wind_gust: WindGust?
    let wind_direction: WindDirection?
    let visibility: Visibility?
    let time: Time?
    let station: String?
    let temperature: Temperature?
    let raw: String?
    let clouds: [Clouds?]
    let wx_codes: [Wxcodes?]
}

struct Clouds: Codable {
    let type: String
    let altitude: Int
}

struct Time: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct WindSpeed: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindGust: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindDirection: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Visibility: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Remarks: Codable {
    let remarks: String
}

struct Altimeter: Codable {
    let repr: String?
    let spoken: String?
}

struct Temperature: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Dewpoint: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Wxcodes: Codable {
    let value: String
}

// WeatherModel

//
//  WeatherModel.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/22/20.
//

import Foundation

struct WeatherModel {
    let reportingStation: String
    let windGust: Int
    let windSpeed: Int
    let windDirection: String
    let visibility: String
    let flightRules: String
    let time: String
    let remarks: String
    let temperature: String
    let dewpoint: String
    let rawMETAR: String
    let lowestCloudsType: String
    let lowestCloudsAlt: Int
    let middleCloudsType: String
    let middleCloudsAlt: Int
    let highestCloudsType: String
    let highestCloudsAlt: Int
    let firstWxCode: String
    
    var windGustString: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "kt", windGust)
    }
    
    
    var windSpeedString: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "kt", windSpeed)
    }
    
    
    var visUnits: String {
        return visibility + " SM"
    }
    
    var degUnits: String {
        return windDirection + "°"
    }
    
    var tempUnits: String {
        return temperature + "°C"
    }
    
    var dewUnits: String {
        return dewpoint + "°C"
    }
    
    var altToString1: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "00 ft", lowestCloudsAlt)
    }
    
    var altToString2: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "00 ft", middleCloudsAlt)
    }
    
    var altToString3: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "00 ft", highestCloudsAlt)
    }
    

    
    var flightConditions: String {
        switch flightRules {
        case "VFR":
            return "green"
        case "MVFR":
            return "blue"
        case "IFR":
            return "red"
        case "LIFR":
            return "purple"
        default:
            return "gray"
        
        }
    }
}

    private func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel? {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)

            
            let clouds = decodedData.clouds
            let wxcodes = decodedData.wx_codes
            let reportingStationVar = decodedData.station ?? "N/A"
            let windGustValue = decodedData.wind_gust?.value ?? 0
            let windSpeedValue = decodedData.wind_speed?.value ?? 0
            let windDirectionValue = decodedData.wind_direction?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let visibilityValue = decodedData.visibility?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let flightRulesValue = decodedData.flight_rules ?? "N/A"
            let timeReportedMETAR = decodedData.time?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let remarksReportedMETAR = decodedData.remarks ?? "N/A"
            let tempMETAR = decodedData.temperature?.repr ?? "No Data"
            let rawMETARData = decodedData.raw ?? "N/A"
            let lowCloudsType = (clouds.count > 0 ? clouds[0]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let midCloudsType = (clouds.count > 1 ? clouds[1]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let highCloudsType = (clouds.count > 2 ? clouds[2]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let lowCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 0 ? clouds[0]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let midCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 1 ? clouds[1]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let highCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 2 ? clouds[2]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let firstWxCode1 = (wxcodes.count > 0 ? wxcodes[0]?.value : "N/A") ?? "N/A"
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(reportingStation: reportingStationVar, windGust: windGustValue, windSpeed: windSpeedValue, windDirection: windDirectionValue, visibility: visibilityValue, flightRules: flightRulesValue, time: timeReportedMETAR, remarks: remarksReportedMETAR, temperature: tempMETAR, dewpoint: rawMETARData, rawMETAR: rawMETARData, lowestCloudsType: lowCloudsType, lowestCloudsAlt: lowCloudsAlt, middleCloudsType: midCloudsType, middleCloudsAlt: midCloudsAlt, highestCloudsType: highCloudsType, highestCloudsAlt: highCloudsAlt, firstWxCode: firstWxCode1)
            
            return weather
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

You will notice that there are some useless functions, like trying fetchWeather at the top of my ContentView. I am trying various things to get data to be pulled but don't know where to put the required:

- the fetchWeather function, and what to initialize
- How to update the views and initialize the WeatherModel or WeatherManager to get that data.

I am new to Swift so I apologize if any part of my question is vague. I am definitely in a bit over my head! Thanks for the help and have a great day.

Add on:

```
//
//  WeatherData.swift
//  SwitUIAppExample
//
//  Created by mac on 30/09/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Kamran. All rights reserved.
//

//
//  WeatherData.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/21/20.
//

import Foundation

struct WeatherData: Codable {
   
    
    let clouds: [Clouds?]
    let flight_rules: String?
    let remarks: String?
    let wind_speed: WindSpeed?
    let wind_gust: WindGust?
    let wind_direction: WindDirection?
    let visibility: Visibility?
    let time: Time?
    let station: String?
    let altimeter: Altimeter?
    let temperature: Temperature?
    let dewpoint: Dewpoint?
    let wx_codes: [Wxcodes?]
    let raw: String?
}



struct Clouds: Codable {
    let type: String
    let altitude: Int
}

struct Time: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct WindSpeed: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindGust: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindDirection: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Visibility: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Remarks: Codable {
    let remarks: String
}

struct Altimeter: Codable {
    let value: Double
}

struct Temperature: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Dewpoint: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Wxcodes: Codable {
    let value: String
}


// WeatherModel

//
//  WeatherModel.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/22/20.
//

import Foundation

struct WeatherModel {
    
    
    let lowestCloudsType: String
    let lowestCloudsAlt: Int
    let middleCloudsType: String
    let middleCloudsAlt: Int
    let highestCloudsType: String
    let highestCloudsAlt: Int
    let reportingStation: String
    let windGust: Int
    let windSpeed: Int
    let windDirection: String
    let visibility: String
    let flightRules: String
    let time: String
    let remarks: String
    let altimeter: Double
    let temperature: String
    let dewpoint: String
    let firstWxCode: String
    let rawMETAR: String
    
    var altToString1: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "00 ft", lowestCloudsAlt)
    }
    
    var altToString2: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "00 ft", middleCloudsAlt)
    }
    
    var altToString3: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "00 ft", highestCloudsAlt)
    }
    
    var windGustString: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "kt", windGust)
    }
    
    
    var windSpeedString: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "kt", windSpeed)
    }
    
    var altimeterString: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f" + " inHg", altimeter as CVarArg)
    }
    
    var visUnits: String {
        return visibility + " SM"
    }
    
    var degUnits: String {
        return windDirection + "°"
    }
    
    var tempUnits: String {
        return temperature + "°C"
    }
    
    var dewUnits: String {
        return dewpoint + "°C"
    }

    
    var flightConditions: String {
        switch flightRules {
        case "VFR":
            return "green"
        case "MVFR":
            return "blue"
        case "IFR":
            return "red"
        case "LIFR":
            return "purple"
        default:
            return "gray"
        
        }
    }
}



// WeatherManager

//
//  WeatherManager.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/21/20.
//

import Foundation

class WeatherManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var weater: WeatherModel?
    
    let weatherURL = "https://avwx.rest/api/metar/"
    

    func fetchWeather (stationICAO: String) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)\(stationICAO)?token=OVi45FiTDo1LmyodShfOfoizNe5m9wyuO6Mkc95AN-c"
        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }
    
    func performRequest (with urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.weater = self.parseJSON(safeData)
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
            print(urlString)
            
            
            }
        }
    
   
    private func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel? {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)

            let clouds = decodedData.clouds
            let wxcodes = decodedData.wx_codes
            let lowCloudsType = (clouds.count > 0 ? clouds[0]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let midCloudsType = (clouds.count > 1 ? clouds[1]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let highCloudsType = (clouds.count > 2 ? clouds[2]?.type : nil) ?? "N/A"
            let lowCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 0 ? clouds[0]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let midCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 1 ? clouds[1]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let highCloudsAlt = (clouds.count > 2 ? clouds[2]?.altitude : nil) ?? 0
            let reportingStationVar = decodedData.station ?? "N/A"
            let windGustValue = decodedData.wind_gust?.value ?? 0
            let windSpeedValue = decodedData.wind_speed?.value ?? 0
            let windDirectionValue = decodedData.wind_direction?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let visibilityValue = decodedData.visibility?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let flightRulesValue = decodedData.flight_rules ?? "N/A"
            let timeReportedMETAR = decodedData.time?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let remarksReportedMETAR = decodedData.remarks ?? "N/A"
            let altimeterMETAR = decodedData.altimeter?.value ?? 0
            let tempMETAR = decodedData.temperature?.repr ?? "No Data"
            let dewMETAR = decodedData.dewpoint?.repr ?? "No Data"
            let firstWxCode1 = (wxcodes.count > 0 ? wxcodes[0]?.value : "N/A") ?? "N/A"
            let rawMETARData = decodedData.raw ?? "N/A"
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(lowestCloudsType: lowCloudsType , lowestCloudsAlt: lowCloudsAlt, middleCloudsType: midCloudsType , middleCloudsAlt: midCloudsAlt, highestCloudsType: highCloudsType , highestCloudsAlt: highCloudsAlt, reportingStation: reportingStationVar, windGust: windGustValue, windSpeed: windSpeedValue, windDirection: windDirectionValue, visibility: visibilityValue, flightRules: flightRulesValue, time: timeReportedMETAR, remarks: remarksReportedMETAR, altimeter: altimeterMETAR, temperature: tempMETAR, dewpoint: dewMETAR, firstWxCode: firstWxCode1, rawMETAR: rawMETARData)
            return weather
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: Thanks for those links. I am struggling because I am trying to pull data from three API sources, and the reason the List API pull model doesn't help me very much is because I am pulling different types of data. For example, in one pull, I may have Doubles, Strings, Ints, and Arrays with different keys to reference each piece.

Comment: I tried to remove MapView/AirportView etc for compilation and made it work to fix the problem. Please check the answer below. Hope it helps fixing it.

Comment: Please check the uploaded code [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/918248ca264fe34827cef814a208b6c120201001030616/a4105a) with the fixes. See chat for more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to introduce few changes as below,

Change `WeatherManager` to `class`, conform to `ObservableObject` and introduce weather model as below,

```
class WeatherManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var weather: WeatherModel?
    
}
```

Rest of the `WeatherManager` will be same except that you need to set the above property after parsing inside `performRequest` method as below,

```
if let safeData = data {
    self.weather = self.parseJSON(safeData)
}
```

Now change `METARReport` by introducing `var model: WeatherModel?` and set all the labels same as time shown below,

```
struct METARReport: View {
    
    var model: WeatherModel?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("METAR Report")
                    .font(.title)
                    
                Spacer()
                Text("Time: " + (self.model?.time ?? ""))
                    .font(.headline)
            }

.....
}
```

Finally just update `METARView` as below,

```
struct METARView: View {

    @State var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    
    init(search: String) {
        self.weatherManager.fetchWeather(stationICAO: search)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
    
        ScrollView{
            // ...
            METARReport(model: weatherManager.weather)
                
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}
```

---

**Note**: There were some parsing issues as well in your code so i used the below models to make it work.

```
struct WeatherData: Codable {
   
    let flight_rules: String?
    let remarks: String?
    let wind_speed: WindSpeed?
    let wind_gust: WindGust?
    let wind_direction: WindDirection?
    let visibility: Visibility?
    let time: Time?
    let station: String?
    let temperature: Temperature?
    let raw: String?
}

struct Clouds: Codable {
    let type: String
    let altitude: Int
}

struct Time: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct WindSpeed: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindGust: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

struct WindDirection: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Visibility: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Remarks: Codable {
    let remarks: String
}

struct Altimeter: Codable {
    let repr: String?
    let spoken: String?
}

struct Temperature: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Dewpoint: Codable {
    let repr: String
}

struct Wxcodes: Codable {
    let value: String
}

// WeatherModel

//
//  WeatherModel.swift
//  AvWx Pro
//
//  Created by Grayson Bertaina on 9/22/20.
//

import Foundation

struct WeatherModel {
    let reportingStation: String
    let windGust: Int
    let windSpeed: Int
    let windDirection: String
    let visibility: String
    let flightRules: String
    let time: String
    let remarks: String
    let temperature: String
    let dewpoint: String
    let rawMETAR: String
    
    var windGustString: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "kt", windGust)
    }
    
    
    var windSpeedString: String {
        return String(format: "%u" + "kt", windSpeed)
    }
    
    
    var visUnits: String {
        return visibility + " SM"
    }
    
    var degUnits: String {
        return windDirection + "°"
    }
    
    var tempUnits: String {
        return temperature + "°C"
    }
    
    var dewUnits: String {
        return dewpoint + "°C"
    }

    
    var flightConditions: String {
        switch flightRules {
        case "VFR":
            return "green"
        case "MVFR":
            return "blue"
        case "IFR":
            return "red"
        case "LIFR":
            return "purple"
        default:
            return "gray"
        
        }
    }
}

    private func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel? {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)

            let reportingStationVar = decodedData.station ?? "N/A"
            let windGustValue = decodedData.wind_gust?.value ?? 0
            let windSpeedValue = decodedData.wind_speed?.value ?? 0
            let windDirectionValue = decodedData.wind_direction?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let visibilityValue = decodedData.visibility?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let flightRulesValue = decodedData.flight_rules ?? "N/A"
            let timeReportedMETAR = decodedData.time?.repr ?? "N/A"
            let remarksReportedMETAR = decodedData.remarks ?? "N/A"
            let tempMETAR = decodedData.temperature?.repr ?? "No Data"
            let rawMETARData = decodedData.raw ?? "N/A"
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(reportingStation: reportingStationVar, windGust: windGustValue, windSpeed: windSpeedValue, windDirection: windDirectionValue, visibility: visibilityValue, flightRules: flightRulesValue, time: timeReportedMETAR, remarks: remarksReportedMETAR, temperature: tempMETAR, dewpoint: rawMETARData, rawMETAR: rawMETARData)
            
            return weather
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great answer! I will mark as correct momentarily - but got an error with ```@State var weatherManager = WeatherManager()``` just under the ```var search: String``` at the start of the METARView View. Where can I initialize the missing property?

Comment: Remove `var search: String` from `METARView`. Just pass it to `fetchWeather` inside `init` as above.

Comment: The error remains: Cannot find 'WeatherManager' in scope

Comment: Please clean + build again. Or restart Xcode. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Still no resolution, and I updated my new ContentView to the post. It is just where the old one is above.

Comment: @GraysonBertaina Not sure about the reason then. Please download the working code i have from [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5c703c2d374aaf493d74ad5d6e258d7d20200930051725/5db919)

Comment: I got it to the point where there are no longer errors but unfortunately when I type in a valid query and hit search on the content view there is no data update or fetch that happens and all of the data values end up showing as my (reference ?? "N/A") N/A values.

Comment: @GraysonBertaina I tested with `OMDB`, `MUX` & `OJAM` in the search and got `temperature` updated correctly. Please verify the shared example.

Comment: Did your temperature show as 25 C? That's the standard value. I tried different codes and the temperature didn't change and I used your downloaded files. Do you think there is something wrong with my simulator?

Comment: Correction! It works... the first time. Can I make an adjustment to allow it to re search when a new query is entered?

Comment: The code i shared works every time you change the search. Please see the console also to verify this. You should be able to see the different URL each time you change the search and it will load the data accordingly.

Comment: Since I still need to access the data in the [Clouds?] and [Wxcodes] array in my decoding, what is wrong with the code I added to my post under Add on? Once I adjusted your code back to this code, it no longer works. I still cannot get it to update again when I resubmit a query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222288/discussion-between-kamran-and-grayson-bertaina).